# Ajax call to refresh a partialview from a controller

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, partial-views

I have the following function in my controller:

```
 public ActionResult DraftOrderDetailsLineItems (Guid customerId)
    {
        //lookup cart based on customer ID
        var draftOrder = new ComApiCart(customerId);

        return PartialView("_draftOrderDetails",draftOrder.OrderDetails);
    }
```

On my view I have this code for the partial

```
  <tbody id="draftOrderItems">
     @Html.Partial("_draftOrderDetails", Model.Order);
  </tbody>
```

Now I need help on the Ajax call. This call first when the tr in the table is clicked to add this item to a cart.  This works fine,  I just need some help after the success to reload the _draftOrderDetails partial view on the view.

```
$(document).on('click', '#search-results tr', function (event) {
//Add to cart
var id = $(this).find('#SKU').val();
var userId = $('#ID').val();
$.ajax({
    url: "/orders/addtocart",
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { "productId": id, "Quantity": 1, "UserID": userID, "Description": "" },
    success: function (data) {

        //ajax call to DraftOrderDetailsLineItems to refresh the lines 

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        productQty.val(0);
        console.error("[Error in Ajax Request, Add To Cart] Code:" + jqXHR.status + " Error:" + errorThrown + " \nText Status:" + jqXHR.responseText);
        timeoutID = window.setTimeout(updateCurrentSession(ACTION.UPDATE), timeoutDelay);
    }
});
```

});

I know I have the customer ID from the Ajax call in the data.id field, I just am struggling to make the call itself to "re-render" the partial view once the item is added to the cart.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can change success part like below and all would be fine.

```js
success: function (data) {

    //ajax call to DraftOrderDetailsLineItems to refresh the lines 
   $.get('/YourController/DraftOrderDetailsLineItems/',{customerId:data.id},function(data){
     $("#draftOrderItems").html(data);
   })
},
```